# how to randomly split a data frame into three smaller ones with given numbers of rows

Tags: r, dataframe

Using R, I want to randomly split a data frame into three smaller data frames. The first one has 80% of the total observations. The second and the third have, respectively, 15% and 5% of the total observations. The three data frames cannot have any overlaps. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This is fairly easy to do.  I've made a function to split into training/testing sets.  It sounds like you want a training/testing/validation split.  You can view my code here: https://github.com/Dasonk/Dmisc/blob/master/R/trainTest.R and you should easily be able to modify it to do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick function to split into an arbitrary number of groups depending on how many values you specify in the 'props' parameter.  It should be fairly self explanatory

```
#' Splits data.frame into arbitrary number of groups
#' 
#' @param dat The data.frame to split into groups
#' @param props Numeric vector. What proportion of the data should
#'              go in each group?
#' @param which.adjust Numeric. Which group size should we 'fudge' to
#'              make sure that we sample enough (or not too much)
split_data <- function(dat, props = c(.8, .15, .05), which.adjust = 1){

    # Make sure proportions are positive
    # and the adjustment group isn't larger than the number
    # of groups specified
    stopifnot(all(props >= 0), which.adjust <= length(props))

    # could check to see if the sum is 1
    # but this is easier
    props <- props/sum(props)
    n <- nrow(dat)
    # How large should each group be?
    ns <- round(n * props)
    # The previous step might give something that
    # gives sum(ns) > n so let's force the group
    # specified in which.adjust to be a value that
    # makes it so that sum(ns) = n
    ns[which.adjust] <- n - sum(ns[-which.adjust])

    ids <- rep(1:length(props), ns)
    # Shuffle ids so that the groups are randomized
    which.group <- sample(ids)
    split(dat, which.group)
}

split_data(mtcars)
split_data(mtcars, c(.7, .3))
```

Comment: After reading through your answer again, I see that mine was too close conceptually and have deleted it. Didn't seem so when I was writing it. Sorry! +1

Answer (score 2):

By manipulating the `parts` vector, you should be able to generate as many unique sets as you want -

```
totrows <- nrow(dat)
rownos <- seq(totrows)
parts <- c(0.8,0.15,0.05)

sets <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(parts))

for( i in seq(parts))
{
  # calculating random % row numbers, % specified by parts[i]
  sets[[i]] <- sample(x = rownos, size = parts[i]*totrows)
  # removing used row nos
  rownos <- setdiff(rownos, sets[[i]])
}
```

If you want overlapping sets, you can remove the `setdiff` statement in the loop.